# Google sheets function for getting value above and below key

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a table with keys in the first column, and values in the second column. What I want to do is sum the values above and below the value corresponding to a given key. So for example, given the following table, given the key b, I would sum 1 and 3. What would be a formula to do so?

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
=SUM(MAP({-1,1},LAMBDA(offset,IFNA(FILTER(B2:B4,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A4))=XMATCH("b",A2:A4)+offset)))))
```

### Update

```
=MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(ζ,IF(ζ="",,SUM(FILTER({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(Sheet1!B2:B,ROWS(Sheet1!A3:A),1),{Sheet1!B4:B;""}},Sheet1!A3:A=ζ)))))
```

Comment: What if I wanted to scale this for a larger table? For example, what if I had a table of 12 keys, and I wanted to sum the numbers above and below for each key?

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qJoQpeQLmfoOnsa1CzUUm0V3Aq8wLhA5ru6jTwqji4I/edit?usp=sharing
It's basically a round robin, and I want to keep track of the series won and lost, and games won and lost. I've got formulas for everything besides the games lost. What I thought about doing was summing the cells above and below the value corresponding to each key since one of those cells is guaranteed to be empty.

Comment: where is the desired result?

Comment: Should be in sheet 2. I highlighted the column I want in green.

Comment: I added the formula in cell F2.